# Hue Solr Search running slow

Tags: solr, cloudera, hue

While displaying data in Hue from Solr (8000+ columns 30000+ rows) Hue is running very slow. It only has 3 users, and is consuming about 7 Gig of memory. Installed through Docker. 
Presumably this is due to the volume of data and not fixable?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant the browser is slow? 8000k columns is a lot, it is recommend to select just a few to display in the grid widget.

Comment: It is slow to open the Hue dashboard on the data, and then is very slow to navigate the dashboard once opened.